# Can't use std::greater where std::less is used

Tags: c++, c++11

This code compiles just fine:

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
std::priority_queue<int> q (std::less<int>{});
```

whereas this code gives weird compilation errors

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
std::priority_queue<int> q (std::greater<int>{});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd template argument for `std::priority_queue` is `std::less` by default. So the constructor you are calling is expecting a `std::less` object. You have to change the 3rd template argument:

```c++
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<T>, std::greater<int>> q (std::greater<int>{});
```

Passing in `std::greater<int>{}` is also unneeded as there's a default constructor to handle that for you.

```c++
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<T>, std::greater<int>> q;
```